# How do I change the color of a parent layout when a fragment is created?

Tags: java, android, fragment

Basically, I want to change an item in the layout that my viewPager is in, when a certain fragment is created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screen_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="471dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So when fragment 1 is created, the text will read "Hello". And then when you swipe to fragment 2, the text will read "World".

Here is my main class.

```
public class screen_main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));
}

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) 
inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) 
{
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ModelObject.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];
        return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
    }
}

public enum ModelObject {

    DEAD(R.string.dead, R.layout.fragment_fragment1),
    BORN(R.string.born, R.layout.fragment_fragment2);

    private int mTitleResId;
    private int mLayoutResId;

    ModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
        mTitleResId = titleResId;
        mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
    }

    public int getTitleResId() {
        return mTitleResId;
    }

    public int getLayoutResId() {
        return mLayoutResId;
    }

}
}
```

And then here is one of the fragment classes.

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public fragment1() {
}

public static fragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    fragment1 fragment = new fragment1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Hello");
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your screen_main activity, add a pageChangeListener to the viewPager. and override the **onPageSelected** method to change the text of textview based on position.

**For instance:**

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            textview.setText(position == 0 ? "Hello" : "World");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: That only works for the first change in position, is there way to make it to where it would change every time?